# VBA if column is Empty then offset (searchlist)

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code which matches data from `"Client Experience"` against `"Admin Upload (Sessions)"`, if looks up the list of names in Column B and match against `"Admin Upload (Sessions)"`.

Once a match is found it copies all the data offset 8 columns to the right from `"Admin Upload (Sessions)"` and paste it into `"Client Experience"` column P onwards with a column spacing of 4 for the next result (if there are more than 1 results).

However the issue is `"Admin Upload (Sessions)"` is a sheet where all admin paste their data and clear it once an upload is done. So every time a new upload is done it will replace all the data in column P in `"Client Experience"` and replace it with the new data.

Could someone please help me with code that searches for the next available column if the current column is filled in `"Client Experience"`.

So as the code runs, for the value in `"B3"` in `"Client Experience"`, it sees that Column P is filled, so it searches for the next column (offset 4) and lands in column T, now that column is filled too, so it searches for the next column again and lands in column X, now column X is empty so it pastes all the data from `"Admin Upload (Sessions)"` in column X & AB (assuming there are 2 return value).

So the code goes to the next rcell which is the value in `"B4"` in `"Client Experience`", it sees that Column P is filled, so it searches the next column and lands in column T, now the column is empty, so it paste all the data.

The code continue running till the end of the range which is `"B202"` following this criteria.

I have entered the code and attached pictures of `"Client experience"` and `"Admin Upload (Sessions)"` for better understanding.

```
Sub test4()

    Dim searchlist As Range
    Dim rcell As Range, sValue As String
    Dim dRange As Range, sCell As Range

    'Values you wish to search data on
    Set searchlist = Sheets("Client Experience").Range("B3:B202")
    'Data Range to search
    Set dRange = Sheets("Admin Upload (Sessions)").Range("A3:A102")

    For Each rcell In searchlist

        lcol = 14

        For Each sCell In dRange

             If InStr(1, sCell.Value, rcell.Value) And Trim(rcell.Value) <> "" Then

                 rcell.Offset(0, lcol).Value = sCell.Offset(0, 8).Value
                 lcol = lcol + 4

             End If

        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

Admin Upload (Sessions)

[image: "Admin Upload (Sessions)"]

Client Experience

[image: Client Experience]

Comment: Seeing the layout of Admin upload might help so as to have an idea of what copies all the data offset 8 columns to the right from "Admin Upload (Sessions)"  means in reality.

Comment: @Qharr definitely, thank you for replying, I will attach it once I am at work tomorrow.